# I got a General Protection Fault while transferring files

Tags: 12.04, kernel, system

SO I was transferring files from one portable hard disk to another (I had two of them connected to the laptop and suddenly the whole thing crashed. Any idea why this could happen? Should I be worried?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

[image]

Comment: Could it have gotten disconnected? Here's someone having a similar error: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1867393.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

With laptops, soometimes it's a lack of power.
Try using external power with both drives. You can get cables which split so you can plug the free end into a USB 5v supply.